# Is it possible to get the bot owner id/name in discordjs v13

Tags: discord.js

i was wondering if there is a way to return an array of bot(team bot) owners id in discordjs instead of me creating a variable in my project and adding each id manually,
i tried `client.application.owner` but it returns null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvm, I guess it doesn't work with team applications. It will always return null
but `client.application.owner` works fine with normal bots.

Answer (score 2):

add this line : `await interaction.client.application.fetch();` before `console.log(interaction.client.application.owner);`